# Gitlab take other version control source

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitblit

In my team we have GitBlit like version control system, and we are interested by GitLab CICD plugins.

If convinced, in the future we could import alls projects but for the moment i would like to use GitlabCI keeping GitBlit like source control.

Is it possible ?

I try the "import project" functionnality but it create a new repository in Gitlab and cut the relation with GitBlit.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [CI definition](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html) (`.gitlab-ci.yml`) is located in a Gitlab repository and is executed when you commit / push to that repository, so in order to really test and experience the full potential of, in my opinion, the awesome CI abilities of Gitlab you should just migrate a repo.

On the other hand I do understand that is not always so easy, so I also have an alternative for you (this is however, advanced usage):

- Create a Gitlab repo with only a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to define the build-steps you want to execute
- Add a `git clone <your GitBlit repo url> .` command to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`'s [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#before_script) to get your GitBlit code in a Gitlab CI job
- Use [triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/triggers/README.html) to run the pipeline when something is pushed to GitBlit by adding a [hook](http://gitblit.com/setup_hooks.html) in GitBlit that sends a POST request to Gitlab

**EDIT based on comment:**

A POST-request will look like this:

```
curl --request POST \
     --form token=TOKEN \
     --form ref=master \
     https://myGitlab/api/v4/projects/1/trigger/pipeline
```

Comment: Have you the POST request url ? I try https://myGitlab/api/v4/projects/1/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token={token} but it doesn't work

Comment: Thats a mix of POST with GET params. Check the edit. Use the HTTP POST method and provide form data to set ref and token.

Comment: Thanks it works well. I had a syntax error on my token string